# sorl-thumbnail: resize original image before saving?

Tags: django, image-processing, django-models, sorl-thumbnail

Using sorl-thumbnail v11.01 and an ImageField on my model is there a simple way to have an uploaded file resized before saving it (to avoid saving a massive image, in case one has been uploaded)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout line 397 [here](https://bitbucket.org/stefanfoulis/sorl-thumbnail/src/845e70ef49a4/docs/index.rst). Although you may not want to use a forked version of the official sorl-thumbnail the code in that fork might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is [django-resized](https://github.com/un1t/django-resized).